# Return cell's value based on its date range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range

I have a table with specific products and  dates and I want to get the cost values that correspond to that date . The source table has a range of dates and not an actual match (that is my problem).
Here is the task: we are trying to fill column "Cost" based on Sheet 2

**SHEET 1:**

| Product | Date | Cost | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 29/12/2021 | ***result 1*** (formula type X) | 100 |
| Second | 05/01/2021 | ***result 2*** (formula type X) | 200 |

The other Sheet has the date ranges with the desired results (selling prices), like this:

**SHEET 2:**

| Product | Start Date | End Date | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 28/12/2020 | 03/01/2021 | ***result 1*** |
| Second | 04/01/2021 | 11/01/2021 | ***result 2*** |

PS. I have different costs for different products in the same date. So, we needed to also add a parameter that will match the Product from one sheet with the product of the other.

Comment: Use SUMIFS perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the given Ranges both start at A1 and end at D3 then the following works in `Sheet1!C2`:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1,(B2>Sheet2!B:B)*(B2<Sheet2!C:C)*(A2=Sheet2!A:A),0))`

This is an array formula to be entered with `ctrl + shift + enter`

It Indexes sheet2 column D and searches for the first match where all mentioned condition are true (=`1`). Each condition produces 1 or 0 for each cell in the range and multiplies it by the result of the cell from the next range in the same row. If either of the conditions is false it multiplies by 0 resulting in 0.
If all conditions are true it will result in 1 (1*1*1).
The overall produces an array of {0,0,1,0,...} and the match function returns the N'th occurance of the first 1, which is equal to the row number of the conditions being true.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. It is a big help. But,  Could you be kind enough to explain the formula you wrote? Why did you put "1" in the Match formula instead of A1 (which is the cell we were searching for) and why is there a multiplication in it? If I use this exact formula I get same cost for every product if the date is 29/12/2020. but I have different costs for different products in the same date.

Comment: Explanation is added, as well as a third condition for matching the product.

Comment: Can this formula "=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1,(B2>Sheet2!B:B)*(B2<Sheet2!C:C)*(A2=Sheet2!A:A),0))"
be converted to Python ? I am getting the time range with datetimerange module but i can't combine it with the Index part (lookup action) of the formula I used in excel.

Comment: I guess the best way is to open a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned tables I'm going to assume you mean a real [Excel Table](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-reasons-to-use-excels-table-object/) and not just cells formatted into a table like appearance.

- Sheet 1 Table is named: `tbl_ProductPrice`
- Sheet 2 Table is named: `tbl_ProductCost`

"Cost" column formula in sheet 1:

```
 =SUMIFS(tbl_ProductCost[Cost],[Date],">="&tbl_ProductCost[Start Date],[Date],"<="&tbl_ProductCost[End Date])
```

**Explanation**

First SUMIFS parameter, "Cost" column, is what will be summed up if all criteria are true.

First IF:

- Second parameter is the date criteria to check.
- Third parameter is what to check against, is greater than or equal to start date.

Second IF:

- Fourth parameter is the date again for the second if statement
- Fifth parameter is checking if less than or equal to the end date.

---

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment regarding multiple product entries for different date ranges I would go with the Index Match approach instead.

```
=INDEX(tbl_ProductCost[Cost],MATCH(1,([@Product]=tbl_ProductCost[Product])*([@Date]>=tbl_ProductCost[Start Date])*([@Date]<=tbl_ProductCost[End Date]),0))
```

Enter formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>since it's an array formula.

I added in a product match as well since you indicated multiple date ranges for each product type.

**Results**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you my friend, but the data are in two different sheets without being converted as tables. Just raw columns and rows. I selected the data range converted them to table (renamed the tables as your formula suggests)and I only get "#Value!" in "cost" column

Comment: See edit - You get the "#Value" error because there are multiple matches.  I saw your comment on the other post and better understand what you are after now.  Try the edit.  FYI - one beauty of tables is that it doesn't matter what sheet they are on.  It's like using workbook named references.

Comment: The second equation is essentially the same as @P.b but using table references and adding product match.

Comment: thank you - very helpful answers from both of you! thank you!